# How should I profile intermittent lags/slowdown for optimization in Java? (see example inside)

Tags: java, performance, optimization, profiling

I'm developing an action-platformer game using Java and just recently finished coding the AI for an enemy unit. I started to notice that at certain points in the game, it would slowdown and lag before going back to normal. See an example here on this video. The lagging part is somewhere at the midpoint of the video and is annotated, so you won't miss it:

[LoGaP 06.14.2013 on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNPwJuiZXjc)

I would guess that there's some code that it tries executing that becomes a bottleneck. Is this typically the symptom of a memory issue or CPU issue?

More importantly, what is the best way in this case to identify what the problematic code is so that I could analyze how to optimize it? The only optimization tool I've only ever used for Java is jvisualvm and I only used it for a while. Will that do the trick in this scenario?

Comment: Tty attaching jvisualvm on your java app, and then use Sampler->CPU while running the program to profile the methods that are consuming the most cpu in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common problem in profiling that you have a method that typically executes in acceptable time, but every once in a while becomes a bottleneck.

Profiling the entire run will likely not help you since the one slow invocation will be drowned out by all the other regular invocations.

In [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), you can mark a method so that exceptional method runs are kept separately and you can examine the slowest operations in detail. You can use the method statistics view to see the call distribution and mark them for exceptional method recording there:

[image]

In the call tree view, the slowest invocations will be marked with an [exceptional run] suffix and you can investigate their call tree in isolation:

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Comment: But then how to deal with lags?